# Ubuntu: command works but as an alias it doesn'T

Tags: ubuntu, alias

```
alias kdd="ps ax|grep -i docker|egrep -iv 'grep|com.docker.vmnetd'|awk '{print $1}'|xargs kill"
```

i'm trying to kill docker desktop and its vm. (I'm inside a vm myself, virtualbox)

pasting the command into the terminal has the desired effect, but calling the alias results in

```
Usage:
 kill [options] <pid> [...]
```

what do i need to change?

Comment: `$1` inside your alias is replaced with an empty string because you have it in double quotes.

Comment: Consider _not using an alias at all_; this would be far easier as a shell function.

Comment: ...mind, if you're on a sane, modern distro you should be using `systemctl` to shut down services, not pipelines with `ps` and `kill`. On a sufficiently modern distro, a service suddenly dying will just cause it to be immediately started up again; so if your goal is for it to stay down, using `kill` may not even _work_.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why This Happens

When you have `$1` inside a double-quoted context (and putting single-quotes inside of double quotes doesn't change the quoting context), it's replaced with the first argument. Interactive shells don't usually have arguments, so typically `$1` in one becomes an empty string; so your awk becomes `{print}`, printing the whole line, not just the first column, so `kill` receives a bunch of arguments that aren't numbers and throws a syntax error.

---

#### Avoiding The Issue

Write this as a function instead of an alias, and you don't need to worry about quote expansion at definition time:

```bash
kdd() {
  ps ax |
    grep -i docker |
    egrep -iv 'grep|com.docker.vmnetd' |
    awk '{print $1}' |
    xargs kill
}
```

Mind, using `systemctl` for the same purpose is far better practice on modern systems (and on pre-modern systems, `pkill` was a better tool for the job).